# Get class type in attribute class

Tags: c#, reflection, attributes, msbuild

I want to validate condition on class definition in the build process and show build error in case that something is not validated.

In the build process attribute instance is created for each class that defined by this attribute.
I want to check something like for example that the class does not have more than 4 properties(just for example, this is not my intention). How can I get the type from the attribute constructor for each class?
(Without passing it as parameter).

Example:

```
    [AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class, AllowMultiple = false)]
    public class ValidatePropertiesAttribute:ValidationAttribute
    {
         public ValidatePropertiesAttribute()
         {
             if(Validate()==false)
             {
                 throw new Exception("It's not valid!! add more properties to the type 'x'.");
             }
         }

         public bool Validate()
         {
             //check if there are at least 4 properties in class "X"  
             //Q: How can I get class "X"?
         }         
    }

    [ValidateProperties()]
    public class ExampleClass
    {
        public string OnOneProperty { get; set; }
    }
```

Is it possbile?

If not, is there any other way to do it?
(add validation to the build process and show errors in case that something was not validated)

Comment: Does anyone know what can be the solution?

Comment: That's not possible.  There's a strong hint that you haven't sufficiently thought about how you are going to implement this.  When you do, you'll discover that passing the type to the Validate() method as an argument is the trivial solution.

Answer (score 3):

This solution may work

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class, AllowMultiple = false)]
public class ValidatePropertiesAttribute:ValidationAttribute
{
     private Type TargetClass;
     public ValidatePropertiesAttribute(Type targetClass)
     {
         TargetClass = targetClass;
         if(Validate() == false)
         {
             throw new Exception("It's not valid!! add more properties to the type 'x'.");
         }
     }

     public bool Validate()
     {
         //Use Target Class, 
         //if you need extract properties use TargetClass.GetProperties()...
         //if you need create instance use Activator..
     }         
}
```

Use this attribute as follows

```
[ValidateProperties(typeof(ExampleClass))]
public class ExampleClass
{
    public string OnOneProperty { get; set; }
}
```